# Why we use jQuery selector with colon?

Tags: jquery

I was recently going through a jquery code where they had used **'div:#idname'** as selector. What is the use of this selector with colon?

here is the link to js file

http://www.amitpatil.me/demos/twitter-like-topwtweets/js/toptweet.jquery.js

Comment: may be a `typo`   ;)

Comment: That would throw `unrecognized expression` error. You might link us to the source?

Comment: i downloaded the demo and it works fine and no error was there. I just used this js in my code and it throws the `unrecognized expression` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none in that example; it's an invalid selector.

The colon is used to introduce [various pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) like state pseudo-classes (`:hover`, `:active`, etc.), structural ones (`:nth-child`, etc.). Two colons are used to introduce [pseudo elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) like `::before` and such, but `div:#idname` is invalid.